# Add hook for specific files

Tags: org-mode, hooks, files, file-local-variables

I am looking to create some customized settings for a specific file. I think I want to add a hook for that file, or something that will create a few settings when that file loads.

For example, I have a file "really-long-lines.org", where every time I open it, I run `M-x toggle-truncate-lines`. By default, I have all files under `org-mode` open with `(toggle-truncate-lines 0)` set. But for this one file, I want it to be set to `(toggle-truncate-lines 1)`. My first approach would be to create a mode for this one file, `really-long-lines-mode`, and run something like this:

```
(add-hook 'really-long-lines-mode
          (lambda()
            (toggle-truncate-lines 1)))
```

But is there a way to add a hook for a specific file? Or whatever solution works best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do it by adding a commented heading to a file:

```
# -*- truncate-lines:1 -*-
```

But this can also be done as file-name specific hook:

```
(defun really-long-lines.org_file_hook ()
  (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) "really-long-lines.org")
    (toggle-truncate-lines 1)
    )
)

(add-hook 'find-file-hook 'really-long-lines.org_file_hook)
```

Comment: Using a variable is indeed better than calling a function; but the variable name is just `truncate-lines`.

Comment: Strange, neither of these solutions is working for me. Perhaps there is a conflict with this setting in my `.emacs`: `(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda() (toggle-truncate-lines 0)`?

Comment: Great, I have it working, although I get a scary warning that it is "not safe", but I loaded it anyway.

Comment: @Lucas: about "not safe" -- next time it will ask you -- just press "!" and it will remember your choise. Hook should be working: I tested it with `(message "hi")`.

Answer (score 5):

A simple answer is to use the `eval` pseudo-variable in a file-local variables block. See the following answer on S.O. for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4356877/324105