# How can I add specific text to the content generated by org-mode export (to Markdown)?

Tags: org-mode, markdown, exporting

This is my org file:

```
#+TITLE: Post title
#+DESCRIPTION: 
#+AUTHOR: MyName
#+DATE: <2022-11-10 Thu>
#+TAGS: tag1 tag2
#+OPTIONS: toc:nil

*Section 1
Content
```

I would like to export it to markdown (`C-c C-e m m`) and have the following content:

```
---
author:
- MyName
date: 2022-11-10 Thu
tags: 'tag1 tag2'
title: 'Post title'
---

# Section 1

Content
```

So the problem comes down to appending some text before the text exported with org-mode exporter by default.

I tried two following approaches. Unfortunately none of them works right.

1. When I add at the beginning of the file:

   ```
   #+begin_export markdown
   ---
   author:
   - {{{author}}}
   date: {{{date}}}
   tags: ?????
   title: 'How to tailor the output of org-mode exporter to our needs'
   ---
   #+end_export
   ```

   the macros are not evaluated. What is more, I don't know how to refer to the #+TAGS field.
2. When I try with:

   ```
   # #+MACRO: newline    src_emacs-lisp[:results raw]{"\n"}
   # #+MACRO: mdheader --- {{{newline}}} author: -{{{author}}} ---

   {{{mdheader}}}
   ```

   the macros are evaluated, however I cannot escape minus signs in macro definition and I obtain:

   ```
   &#x2014; 
   author: -MyName &#x2014;
   ```

   in the markdown output file. Besides, in this approach there also exist a problem with accessing tag names.

How can those snippets be corrected to get desired result? Or is there any better way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a global macro as follows:

```lisp
(defun org-export-md-format-front-matter ()
  (let* ((kv-alist (org-element-map (org-element-parse-buffer 'greater-element)
                       'keyword
                     (lambda (keyword)
                       (cons (intern (downcase (org-element-property :key keyword)))
                             (org-element-property :value keyword)))))
         (lines (mapcar (lambda (kw)
                          (let ((val (alist-get kw kv-alist)))
                            (format (pcase kw
                                      ('author "%s: %s")
                                      ((or 'tags 'title) "%s: '%s'")
                                      (_ "%s: %s"))
                                    (downcase (symbol-name kw))
                                    (pcase kw
                                      ('date (substring val 1 -1))
                                      (_ val)))))
                        '(author date tags title))))
    (concat "---\n" (concat (mapconcat #'identity lines "\n")) "\n---")))

(setq org-export-global-macros
      '((front-matter . "(eval (org-export-md-format-front-matter))")))
```

additionally, as described in [the footnotes (currently 108)](https://orgmode.org/org.html#FOOT108) in section [Special Symbols](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Special-Symbols) of the org manual, you can toggle the 'special' exporting of `-` via [the - export setting](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Export-Settings), i.e. add:

```
#+OPTIONS: -:nil
```

to the keywords at the start of your org file.

These two things should do the trick...

---

Alternatively, you can use the [`org-export-before-processing-hook`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) to run a function that inserts the desired string (e.g. as produced by the function `org-export-md-format-front-matter` above) before any other processing is done:

```el
(defun my/org-export-markdown-hook-function (backend)
    (if (eq backend 'md)
        (insert (org-export-md-format-front-matter) "\n")))

(add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'my/org-export-markdown-hook-function)
```

---

If you prefer to run this function only with 'specific' files, then you can add the hook only locally in those files using a [File Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html). In this case, do not add the hook globally (as in the example above), but add a file variable to the end of your 'specified' files as follows:

```
# Local Variables:
# eval: (add-hook 'org-export-before-processing-hook #'my/org-export-markdown-hook-function nil t)
# End:
```

(Caution! Remember that after adding these lines not only saving (`C-x C-s`) but also *reloading* the file from the disk (
`C-x C-v RET` or
`M-x revert-buffer`) is necessary to make Emacs load the local variables.)

Alternatively, you could add a condition to only add the front matter when the file is a member of a list of specified filenames, as follows:

```lisp
(defun my/org-export-markdown-hook-function (backend)
  (if (and (eq backend 'md)
           (member buffer-file-name '("/path/to/some/org-file.org"
                                      "/path/to/another/org-file.org")))
      (insert (org-export-md-format-front-matter) "\n")))
```

Comment: I added an alternative way to your answer. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: And BTW, thanks for footnote 109 !-) TIL...

Comment: I don't mind at all, on the contrary, it is a nice improvement! It adds the possibility to selectively (on backend) insert the 'front matter'. I took the macro path, as I first only wanted to use it to get the "TAGS", but then I thought I could as well add (and format)  the other 'Export Settings' (to have it all in one macro). So I did not think about using the hook, which looks preferable to me (in most cases).

Comment: Thank you. It almost works. I just need to ask for one last hint (sorry, this lisp syntax is still too difficult for me). It seems that I need to have the keywords (author, title, etc.) in lowercase. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Change `(format "%s: %s" kw ...)` in the `org--export-md-format-front-matter` function to `(format "%s: %s" (downcase kw) ...)`. That formats the string that is printed out not with the original keyword `kw` but with the lower case version of it produced by calling the function `downcase` on it.

Comment: I've added the downcase to the answer, as it should be there to correctly answer the original answer... @NickD thanks for 'jumping in'

Comment: I have added some code to make the formatting match better with the format in the question. Unfortunately, when adding a single newline within the formatting of the author keyword, then somehow two newlines get exported. Therefore, I hope that the current formatting is correct. Of course, if it is not, then we could add some additional tricks to fix it.

Comment: I've got it working. Thanks again guys! The downside of your solution is that it changes the behaviour of markdown exporter for all .md files, whilst it'd be perfect if I could invoke it only for specific files (I know, I didn't specified this requirement earlier) . I tried to supplement your code with one of those ideas ([1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14760/add-hook-for-specific-files), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4356472/emacs-per-file-customization/4356877#4356877) ) but with no success. Still, your solution does the job.

Comment: I've added two options to achieve what you want. You were on the right path (you can make a hook local by passing a non-nil LOCAL argument).

Comment: @dalanicolai OK. Finally, I've managed to get things working. Since it took me some time to find out what was the reason your code wasn't working at first, I decided to add a comment about the necessity of reloading the file after inserting "Local Variables" lines. I hope you don't mind.